# Change the SD card directory for a single app?

Tags: android

Let's say I have app X. When I launch app X, it searches for `abc.xyz` anywhere in /sdcard.

But say I don't have an SD card. How can I remount /sdcard as, say, /abc instead?

Basically, I want the app to look for the files in /abc instead of /sdcard? Is this possible without changing the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it on a rooted device or customized Android firmware built by yourself.

The app might be looking for

```
1. Hard coded path name "/sdcard/"
2. Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

To deak with each case:

1. You can mount other folder to /sdcard, or simply create a soft link to your destination directory (rooted device or customized firmware)
2. You need to modify the framework API code (customized firmware only)